# Python Module not found when it is clearly present in /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/

Tags: python, linux, gnuradio

It seems like a very simple problem

we can see below that `gnuradio.ctrlport` can be imported
But `gnuradio.ctrlport.GNURadioControlPortClient` fails.
This would indicate that the `GNURadioControlPortClient.py` file is missing right?

```
bit@bit:~$ python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gnuradio
>>> import gnuradio.ctrlport
>>> import gnuradio.ctrlport.GNURadioControlPortClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio.ctrlport.GNURadioControlPortClient'
```

Next we can see that the file with the same name does exist in the gnuradio/ctrlport directory! This doesn't make sense as I don't get how python cannot import a file that clearly is present.

```
bit@bit:/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/gnuradio/ctrlport$ ls
GNURadio                       GNURadioControlPortClient.pyo  GrDataPlotter.pyo  __init__.pyc  monitor.pyc       RPCConnection.pyc       RPCConnectionThrift.pyc
GNURadioControlPortClient.py   GrDataPlotter.py               icon.png           __init__.pyo  monitor.pyo       RPCConnection.pyo       RPCConnectionThrift.pyo
GNURadioControlPortClient.pyc  GrDataPlotter.pyc              __init__.py        monitor.py    RPCConnection.py  RPCConnectionThrift.py
```

Sys.path returns the correct value.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/bit/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

so I believe it is searching in the correct directory. But it can't find it.

For reference this error is for the `gr-perf-monitorx` tool for GNURADIO which is importing this file but failing.

EDIT: Added the local path to the code and it worked see the comment below

Comment: `Sys.path returns the correct value.` There is no `/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages` entry there, what do you mean by "correct".

Comment: That worked. Sorry I didn't notice it.